# How can I upload multiple .npy files to consolidate into one array?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab

I want to eventually convert my array files into a matlab matrix, but I don't want to convert each file one by one since I have hundreds of files.

So far, I was able to convert using this below-

```
from scipy.io import savemat
import numpy as np

temp = np.load(r"C:\Desktop\Python\example.npy")
savemat("matlab_matrix.mat", {"data":temp})
```

Is there a command that could scan through the entire folder and maybe consolidate all npy files for my conversion?

Answer (score 0):

With `listdir` in `os` module, you can get the files and the folders in the current directory or any specific directory.

```
from scipy.io import savemat
import numpy as np
import os
        
npyfiles = []
path = "Folder Path"
files_list = os.listdir(path)
for file in files_list:
    if files.endswith(".npy"):
       npyfiles.append(file)

for file in npyfiles:
    temp = np.load(file)
    savemat("matlab_matrix.mat", {"data":temp})
```